# Where is GDB documentation specific to the Cell Linux environment?

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, cell

Where can documentation be found for the features of GDB, and the debugging process, specific to debugging of Cell Linux programs mixing PPU and SPU code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documents at the IBM developerWorks site for Cell can be found here:
[Cell @developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/power/cell/documents.html?S_TACT=105AGX16&S_CMP=LP)

You sound like you'd want the [Programmer's Guide](http://www.ibm.com/chips/techlib/techlib.nsf/techdocs/1DAAA0A3B6404763002573530066008C?Open&S_TACT=105AGX16&S_CMP=LP), which goes through debugging Cell applications.

Edit to add sample topics:

- Chapter 3. Debugging Cell BE applications

  - ...
  - Debugging PPE code
  - Debugging SPE code
  - ...
  - Debugging in the Cell BE environment
  - Debugging multithreaded code
  - Debugging architecture
  - Switching architectures within a single thread
  - ...
  - Using the combined debugger
  - ...

Answer (score 1):

One comprehensive overview seems to be here http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg247575.html?Open